# meshing a map using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am trying to render a map using a topojson file I converted from the following geojson: [Nigeria Wards in GeoJSON](http://data.ehealthafrica.org/dataset/administrative-boundaries-nigeria-ward/resource/1cc0df2d-73ed-451b-9265-c90de2ed222a?inner_span=True)

I am using the npm [topojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson) converter to convert the file to a topojson like so:

```
 topojson -o nig.json result.json
```

However, when I implement meshing in d3, it looks like this:

[image: topojson nigeria]

As you can see, some borders have been drawn correctly, but most of the meshes are rubbish.

I think either the data must be corrupt or my conversion went incorrect.
Did anyone else had this issue and knows how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
/* CSS goes here. */

#map {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-dasharray: 2,2;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var width = $('#map').width(),
        height = $('#map').height();

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([0.732, 0.540])
        .scale(4000)
        .translate([width / 10, height]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("nig.json", function(error, n) {
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.feature(n, n.objects.result))
            .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(n, n.objects.result))
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "borders");
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

did it!, used the http://mapshaper.org/ to compress my map to 5% of it's size. Now that it uses less datapoints it seems to work just fine. [image]